# Prove of $E\left(|X+Y|^a\right)\ge E\left(|Y|^a\right)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, expected-value

Let $E(V)$ be the expectation of $V$.
It is also known that $E(X)=0, a>1, E\left(|X|^a\right) < +\infty$ and $E\left(|Y|^a\right)< +\infty$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
How can I prove that $E\left(|X+Y|^a\right)\ge E\left(|Y|^a\right)$?

Comment: What is $V$ here? You mean $Y$?

Comment: No, it is only explanation what is E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a>1$, the function $f: x\mapsto |x|^a$ is convex. (Of course this is true for $a\ge1$, too.)
Your result follows from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#General_inequality_in_a_probabilistic_setting): conditional on $Y$ we have $E(f(X+Y)|Y) \ge f(E(X+Y|Y))=f(Y)$.  And so on.

Comment: Your Jensen is the wrong way around.

Comment: Whoops: so it is!  Thanks for the catch.